# What are best practices to make sure automised import routines are running correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am an intern in a company with not much tech knowledge so I am learning pretty much everything as I go. Now we have an SQL database that people mainly use in Access. I am currently working on automising a lot of the workflows that go along our database using mostly SSIS. Now one of the issues I am having when automising a lot of these tasks is that the visibility of what is happening gets lost. For example when importing data. Before the routines where set up in a way where people would consolidate the data manually in excel and then run a simple append query, thus knowing exactly what they are importing and maybe even spotting some human error that happened in the original data.

Now I automised these routines to consolidate the data from multiple files and then import them automatically, but this means that nobody knows exactly what is being imported if that makes sense.

Comment: Broad and unclear.   What information are you trying to get out of your automated routines?    Be specific.

Comment: You have forgotten to ask a question. You provided a vague description of how a process changed. I can make an assumption or two but this just isn't answerable currently.

Comment: You only **automated** (automised?) part of the process and omitted what is now recognized as an important function. That of capturing (and reviewing) what was loaded. So - log that information and provide a way to access it. How to do that requires more knowledge about the original process, who does what, your automation details, etc.

Comment: @Smor You are correct with your assessment and I do agree that for a concrete answer I would need to provide a lot more information, which goes far beyond what I gave so far. I am also prepared to do the researching on my own. I was more hoping for some direction into what to look for. Or even what to google for, because I have no idea of what is possible in this regard.